# Error no matching VNC server running for this user

Tags: linux, kali-linux, vnc

guys, I'm running Kali Nethunter but when I try to run it in graphical mode by running the command `kex &` I have this error:

```
vncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user!
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. You just need to run this:

```
cd /root/.vnc
```

and then:

```
rm -fr xstartup
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i fixed it.

`vncserver -localhost no`

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209147/tigervncviewer-unable-to-connect-to-socket-connection-refused-10061