# No matching VNC server running for this user!

Tags: linux, kali-linux, upgrade, vnc

I'm using Kali Nethunter, and I need help to fix this. 
I've been using the command `nethunter -r kex &` and I'm getting this error:

```
vncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user!
vncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user!
Error starting the KeX server.
Please try "nethunter kex kill" or restart your termux session and try again.
```

This happened after I gave the command `apt upgrade`. 
How can I fix this?

To answer the follow-up questions (in comments):

- Yes, I tried `nethunter kex kill`.
- No, I did not get any yes/no prompts like "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]".

Comment: I'm presuming you were prompted  with "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]" and you replied with "Y".  Did  you restart your Kex server as directed? And at some point you may be forced to reboot - it will depend upon what was upgraded. If all everything else fails, then reboot the machine.

Comment: It doesn't appear with s / n it just shows that error above, this happened after I gave an apt upgrade and I don't know what upgraded and now it's not working, and worse that I found this problem on Google, but it doesn't have answers on how to fix it

Comment: Have you tried `nethunter kex kill`? And did you ask this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640137/error-no-matching-vnc-server-running-for-this-user/640685#640685.

Comment: Yes I already did Nethunter kex kill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u still haven't find how to solve this please do following steps

1. Delete .vnc folder under /root derectory
2. now delete all the files inside of tmp folder including hidden...note: don't delete tmp folder
3. Now make new server using command :- vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080
4. provide new password and run vnc viewer on new port

Answer (score 1):

Hey guy's I had encountered the same problem but fortunately I have quick solution to fix it.

Follow the steps

1. long press the termux app and go Press "Force stop"
2. open termux app
3. again make new password for nethunter kex just type "nethunter kex passwd"
4. after you set the password type "nethunter kex &"
5. it will reset and give you a new port for nethunter kex app
6. go to nethunter kex app and set the port and put the password
7. It works perfectly fine :)
8. please give feedback .thanks

Comment: It didn't work :( it happened after I upgraded so I think maybe this is a side effect of a new version of tigervnc

Comment: The last options you might wanna do is to re install the kali linux on termux and remove all the files

Comment: This would be very impractical, I installed literally all the standard tools of Kali Linux which is making the termux weigh 30gb I would have to uninstall all this to install it again

Comment: You got  a point tho... :( But have you find any other way to fix it???.